# Computer Won’t Turn On or Charge

Tags: battery, power, charging

I have an issue with my Acer Aspire E5-575 when it will not turn on, or charge.

I followed the support guides on Acer’s website as well as various articles that I found on Google.

What are some things that I can do to get the computer to turn on again.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried checking your charger ? Try a different charger I mean

Comment: @pun Yes, I bought another changer and tried it. I got no result.

Comment: @JamesP I don't think it is under warranty